# html dom element ckeditor tag clean up

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a problem; when i attach ckeditor to an element and then try to retrieve html using dom element i get dirty markup.
Is there some ckeditor function that clears up that markup or do I need to create something custom?

example code:

```
$(".editor").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
    var test = CKEDITOR.inline(this);
    test.on( 'blur', function( evt ) {
        $.post(window.location.href, { task: "change-content", html: $(".content-container")[0].outerHTML })
          .done(function( data ) {
              //window.location.reload();
        }.bind(this));
     });
});
```

html code original:

```
<div class="content-container">
<div class="editor">First editor</div>
<div class="editor">Second editor</div>
<div class="editor">Third editor</div>
</div>
```

Retrieved html with function

```
<div class="content-container">
<div class="editor cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_102" style="position: relative;" contenteditable="true">First editor</div>
<div class="editor cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_102" style="position: relative;" contenteditable="true">Second editor</div>
<div class="editor cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_102" style="position: relative;" contenteditable="true">Third editor</div>
</div>
```

Is there some ckeditor function that clears these tags up from dom element?
Or i should create a custom function?

**UPDATE:**

Silly solution:

```
        var text = $(".content-container")[0].outerHTML;
        text = text.replace(/ cke_editable/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ cke_editable_inline/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ cke_contents_ltr/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ cke_show_borders/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ contenteditable=\"true\"/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ tabindex=\"0\"/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ spellcheck=\"false\"/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ role=\"textbox\"/g, "");

        text = text.replace(/ aria-label=\"Rich Text Editor, editor\d+\"/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ title=\"Rich Text Editor, editor\d+\"/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/ aria-describedby=\"cke_\d+\"/g, "");

        text = text.replace(/ style=\"position: relative;\"/g, "");
        text = text.replace(/editor_inline\"/g, "editor");
```

If anyone has better solution fell free to add it here :)

Comment: Did you check the update?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `evt.editor.getData()` - it will give you the cleaned html.

```
$(".editor").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
    var test = CKEDITOR.inline(this);
    test.on( 'blur', function( evt ) {
        $.post(window.location.href, { 
            task: "change-content", 
            html: evt.editor.getData() 
        })
          .done(function( data ) {
              //window.location.reload();
        }.bind(this));
     });
});
```

### Update

If you need to combine the content of all the editors you can use:

```
finalHtml = ''
for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    finalHtml += CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].getData();
}
```

You can put this code inside the `test.on( 'blur', function( evt ) {` event and send the complete content to your server (using the `$.post` function) :

```
$(".editor").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
    var test = CKEDITOR.inline(this);
    test.on( 'blur', function( evt ) {
        finalHtml = ''
        for (var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            finalHtml += CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].getData();
        }
        $.post(window.location.href, { 
            task: "change-content", 
            html: finalHtml
        })
          .done(function( data ) {
              //window.location.reload();
        }.bind(this));
     });
});
```

Comment: Yes. but it gives only html inside that element.

Comment: i want clean html from ".content-container" class, but that function will give only one ".editor" inner html.. 

But thanks for response. :)